# USQL Activity in ADF V2 - 2705 User is not able to access to datalake store

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm facing an issue when running a U-SQL Script with Azure Data Factory V2.

This U-SQL Script work fine in the portal or vs :

```
 @a  = 
  SELECT * FROM 
    (VALUES
       ("Contoso",   1500.0, "2017-03-39"),
       ("Woodgrove", 2700.0, "2017-04-10")
    ) AS D( customer, amount );

@results =
  SELECT
    customer,
    amount
  FROM @a;    

OUTPUT @results
  TO "test"
  USING Outputters.Text();
```

But don't work when started in Azure Data Factory V2 Activity, bellow my ADF scripts.

```
Creating or updating linked service ADLA [adla] ...
{
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
    "typeProperties": {
      "accountName": "adla",
      "servicePrincipalId": "ea4823f2-3b7a-4c-78d29cffa68b",
      "servicePrincipalKey": {
        "type": "SecureString",
        "value": "jKhyspEwMScDAGU0MO39FcAP9qQ="
      },
      "tenant": "41f06-8ca09e840041",
      "subscriptionId": "9cf053128b749",
      "resourceGroupName": "test"
    }
  }
}

Creating or updating linked service BLOB [BLOB] ...
{
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": {
        "type": "SecureString",
        "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=totoblob;AccountKey=qZqpKyGtWMRXZO2CNLa0qTyvLTMko4lzfgsg07pjloIPGZtJel4qvRBkoVOA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
      }
    }
  }
}

Creating or updating pipeline ADLAPipeline...
{
  "properties": {
    "activities": [
      {
        "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
        "typeProperties": {
          "scriptPath": "src/test.usql",
          "scriptLinkedService": {
            "referenceName": "blob",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
          },
          "degreeOfParallelism": 1
        },
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "adla",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "name": "Usql-toto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

1 - I checked the connection to the blob storage, the u-sql script is successfully found (if i rename it, it throw a not found error)

2 - I checked the connection to azure data lake analytics, it seems to connect, if i set a wrong credential it throw an other error

3 - When running the pipeline I Have the following error : "Activity Usql-toto failed: User is not able to access to datalake store" and actually I don't provide Data Lake Store Credential but there is a default datalake store account attached ADLAnalytics.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found help in this post: [U-SQL Job Failing in Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925343/u-sql-job-failing-in-data-factory)

Folders system and catalog **doesn't** inherit from parent permissions ... So I had to reassign permission on this two folders.

Comment: permissions for new folders/files are inherited from the default-permissions of the parent folder. Have you set those?

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem. What helped me was running the "Add User Wizard" from Data Lake Analytics. Using this wizard I added the service principal that I use in the linked service for Data Lake Analytics as an Owner with R+W permissions.

Before using the wizard, I tried to configure this manually by setting appropriate permissions from the Explore data screen, but that didn't resolve the problem. (SP was already contributor on the service)

Comment: I found this was important as for every day new folders were getting added but they weren't inheriting the permissions correctly thus ever day change my data factory scripts started failing.

Comment: This works like a charm!  I faced the same issue, strange to see that adding SP as a contributor role to ADLA didn't help.